# Single Sign On error message "FBTOAU204E An invalid secret was provided for the client"

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am recently having an error which I have traced back to the binded service for my application - Single Sign On. I have tried reverting any changes made to the application to a date when it worked but that did not resolve.

I have a link within the online application for an admin user to log in. The link opens for me to sign in - when I select sign in this used to log me in using the single sign in and take me to the admin view. But now I get this error message:-

> "**OAuth 2.0 - error
>
> The following error was encountered while processing your OAuth
>   request:
>
> Error Code: invalid_client
>
> Error Description: FBTOAU204E An invalid secret was provided for the
>   client with identifier: 'null'."**

After some investigation the error seems to be due to the single sign on details....but I have been unable to find an answer as to how or where to rectify this.

I have read on forums that the SSO version has changed so could be the issue but I have also read that existing applications with the original SSO service should still work. I have tried to add some screen shots to show SSO details but my reputation is not high enough to allow me to do that!

If any further info is needed to help with this please let me know.
Any help or pointers appreciated!

**SSO Credentials:-**

```
{
  "user-provided": [
    {
      "name": "Single Sign On -Assessments",
      "label": "user-provided",
      "credentials": {
        "profile_resource": "https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/idaas/resources/profile.jsp",
        "tokeninfo_resource": "https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/idaas/resources/tokeninfo.jsp",
        "token_url": "https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/sps/oauth20sp/oauth20/token",
        "authorize_url": "https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/sps/oauth20sp/oauth20/authorize"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**SSO Code excerpt:-**

```
public class SSOService {

    final static String SERVICE_NAME = "single.sign.on";
    final static String DEFAULT_OAUTH_PROFILE_RESOURCE = "https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/idaas/resources/profile.jsp";
    final static String DEFAULT_OAUTH_TOKENINFO_RESOURCE = "https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/idaas/resources/tokeninfo.jsp";
    final static String DEFAULT_OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/sps/oauth20sp/oauth20/token";
    final static String DEFAULT_OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT = "https://idaas.ng.bluemix.net/sps/oauth20sp/oauth20/authorize";

    JSONObject _creds = null;

    protected SSOService() {
        VCAPServices vcs;
        try {
            vcs = new VCAPServices();
            _creds = vcs.getCredentials(SERVICE_NAME);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            _creds = null;
        }
    }

    public String getOAuthProfileResource() {
        return getCredential("profile_resource", DEFAULT_OAUTH_PROFILE_RESOURCE);
    }

    public String getOAuthTokenInfoResource() {
        return getCredential("tokeninfo_resource",
                DEFAULT_OAUTH_PROFILE_RESOURCE);
    }

    public String getOAuthTokenEndpoint() {
        return getCredential("token_url", DEFAULT_OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT);
    }

    public String getOAuthAuthorizeEndpoint() {
        return getCredential("authorize_url", DEFAULT_OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_ENDPOINT);
    }

    String getCredential(String attrName, String defaultValue) {
        String result = null;
        if (_creds != null) {
            try {
                result = _creds.getString(attrName);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                result = null;
            }
        }

        if (result == null) {
            System.err.println("Unable to get credential: " + attrName
                    + " from VCAP_SERVICES, using default: " + defaultValue);
            result = defaultValue;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a code excerpt? You're right that SSO V2 replaced the prior version earlier this year and V1 is no longer available: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/177276/how-to-apply-client-id-secret.html

Comment: Please post a code excerpt.  Part of Stackoverflow is showing some of the code you have tried.

Comment: @dan_cairns Sent a message to someone that knows how to do this, they will be posting shortly.

Comment: @Jeff Sloyer - Thankyou